# apt-get with quiet option is still noisy

Tags: bash, apt-get

Trying to use apt-get in a script, so I'm using the `apt-get -qq -y` option, as I want to have my install script show something like...

```
Installing SUDO....DONE
```

But for some reason apt-get is still producing lots of output, with this option, which means I end up getting...

```
Installing SUDO....
Selecting previously unselected package sudo.
(Reading database ... 48056 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../sudo_1.8.10p3-1+deb8u5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking sudo (1.8.10p3-1+deb8u5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u5) ...
Setting up sudo (1.8.10p3-1+deb8u5) ...
DONE
```

So my install script just looks messy for a basic package install, let alone for all the other packages.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

Try to run `sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -qq sudo < /dev/null > /dev/null`

Source: https://peteris.rocks/blog/quiet-and-unattended-installation-with-apt-get/

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I have tried the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` approach too, and get the same result.  I also prefer to not use the `> /dev/null` approach too, in case it does actually have some important information I needs to share.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example that is totally quiet and does not output any line on my machine including warnings. Used 2>/dev/null to disable warnings as well

```
!apt install octave -qq 2>/dev/null >/dev/null;
```